# How can I convert a PHP hex array, to ascii? \x76\x52\x9

Tags: php, hex

How can I convert a PHP hex array, to ascii?
Ex. if I have this string:

```
$var1="\x76\x52\x9\x3a\x5b\x79";
```

When I echo it, it appears right, but I'd like to convert it to ascii in the program, so I can do further processing on it & use it further in the script.

Comment: What other processing are you talking about that can't handle that?  If I `preg_match` for "y", it will match it which means internally PHP converts it to ascii for you, at least for regex patterns.  I also tested it with `===` operator with the hex value and the string value and it returned a bool(true) value.

Answer (score 1):

The string is already as you want it. The hex notation is just that: a notation. In reality the string has 6 characters:

```
echo strlen($var1);
```

Output:

```
6
```

And this:

```
echo $var1 === "vR\t:[y";
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

Which means they are equal. Note that I still had to escape the tab character with a backslash, but also that is just notation. In reality the tab character is there and is one character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php
 $var1 = '\x76\x52\x9\x3a\x5b\x79';

echo hexa_string($var1);

function hexa_string($hex_str)
{
$string='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex_str)-1; $i+=2)
{
    $string .= chr(hexdec($hex_str[$i].$hex_str[$i+1]));
}
return $string;
}
?>
```